# Ankh of Retribution and Item acquisition

Tags: werewolv.es

If player A carries the Ankh of Retribution and is killed by player B, player B dying the next night, does player A receive player B's items as per general rules of receiving the Items of somebody you kill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the killer would receive the items as normal, even though they are dead by this point.